# Looking up a mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express

so I have implemented a register page that sends the inputs into a mongoDB atlas. However, I am trying to implement a new page where users are able to login. I am having trouble trying to find the specific key: value pair in order to check my inputs.

My mondoDB atlas shows the following:

```
_id: 62da20a99df697486c4b12cc
username: "hello"
password: "hello"
__v: 0
```

My function for logging in is the below:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  if (await User.find({ username: req.body.username })) {
    console.log("do smth");
  }}
```

For now, lets just ignore the console.log() as I just want to see whether its going through or not. It's always evaluating to true and I don't know why. I can type any input and it always goes through but I'm not sure why its always evaluating to true so I know for sure I'm not looking up at the database correctly.

The

```
User.find()
```

where

```
User
```

is the name of the variable I defined when requiring the file I defined my schema. Any help would be appreciated in terms of how I should look up a key which in this case is username and I want to look up  the req.params.username to see if that actually exists in my database.

Updated CODE

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  if (
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
      console.log(user);
    })
  ) {
    res.send("YES");
  } else {
    res.send("NO");
  }
```

If the input is in the database, it will log the user which in this case is

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62daeb740c2c6e2b61325151"),
  username: '123',
  password: '123',
  __v: 0
}
```

However, if its not in the database, it will log null but the if statement still evaluates to true.

Comment: Have you tried to log the return value of `User.find`…?

Comment: Yes, I have. It has a really long output that i've attached part of it below: 

Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'Users',

Answer (score 1):

`User.find` returns an array, which may be empty or not, but is never false in the Javascript sense. By contrast [`User.findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne) returns an object, or `null` if nothing is found, and `null` does not satisfy the `if` condition. Probably that's what you want.

If `User.findOne` returns a `Query`, you can try invoking it with a callback function:

```js
User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
  if (err)
    console.error(err);
  else if (user) {
    console.log("do smth");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you said, but it seems to always be evaluating to true regardless. All I did was change from User.find to User.findOne(), but it keeps evaluating to true. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Does my augmented answer help?

Comment: Hmm, It just logs "do smth" which I don't get why it keeps doing. I've tried inputting something that doesn't exist in the database.

 So what I am trying to do is logging in and I want to see  if it already exists in the database. I created a register page  that registers users and used urlencoded with express. It shows up in my mongodb, but whenever I'm trying to login, it always evaluates to true.

Comment: Replace `console.log("do smth")` with `console.log(user)` to see which object has been returned.

Comment: Okay, I did. 

I get the below { _id: new ObjectId("62d91bf94b4d482bbe735681"), __v: 0 }. 

Also my original code had an if await, would I still keep that in order to debut what is actually happening?

Comment: No, the `if await` syntax is an _alternative_ to the callback syntax. But both are probably equivalent. The question is why do you get back a user with an `_id` but without a `username`? To be answered by mongodb experts.

Comment: Hello, sorry I am a little bit confused. Could you elaborate a bit more on the await syntax is an alternative to the call back syntax?

Comment: See the documentation in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne

Comment: Hello, I think I found something. So in my mongoDB there were a few objects that didn't have a username or password. It just was just the _id and nothing else. I deleted everything in my mongoDB and created a new user. However, I still can't seem to search up that new User and I don't know why.

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix the correct output. So IF the user does exist in my mongoDB it logs the user, otherwise it returns null (so that's good news since that is what we except) But for some reason my if statement is still always evaluating to true. In other words, even though it logs null, it still evaluates to true.

Comment: Please update the question with your most recent code.

Comment: I just updated it, it's at the bottom of the page under updated code. I used res.send() just so its easier for me to know if its working or not.

Comment: The `if` must be inside the callback function, like in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to your code(just copy pasted). So what happens now is that if i input something in the database, it logs the user. However, if I enter something that is not in the database, then nothing gets logged

Comment: An `else` branch is needed for the case where no user is found.